# Make node js - express application support multiple users

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I have create a hangman game in the following stack 
bootstrap, jQuery and JavaScript for front-end
Express and Node.js for back-end.

Here is the sample code:

```
const express = require('express');
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Start playing the game on port 3000");
});
```

I am using jQuery AJAX requests to talk to the node server

```
 $.post("/guess/", data, function(data, status){
    //do something with data
});
```

That request is captured in express's app.post methods

```
app.post('/guess/', function(req, res){
    //do something
});
```

The game is running as expected and no problems in the code alone.
 
The problem is that whenever I open `http://localhost:3000` in two tabs or browsers and play the game in both of them, the game seems broken. Both games of `localhost` seem to be working on the same server variables and instances.

For example, if I play the game in browsers 1 and 2 and I have guessed in browser 1 the letter 'a' (a wrong guess) the result for that is reflected in browser 1, the base of hangman is drawn. 
[image: browser 1]

After that if I go to browser 2 and click letter 'b'(a wrong guess, again), the result should be the base of hangman, but the next part of hangman is drawn instead of the base. The count variable keeping track of wrong guesses is being updated by both instances of `localhost`.
[image: browser 2]

Any idea on how I can support multiple instances of the web application with the above setup?

Comment: Multiple instances? You don't need that, you just need to identify a session and a user. But browser tabs to the URL generally share a session, so you'd need a token generated on the initial render that would then be sent with each request to uniquely identify that particular "game" or "user".

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Also what is an instance vs session? Just to make sure we speak about the same things.

Comment: An instance is a separate server or port listener. A session is just that-it's common vocabulary for web apps. How? Generate a uuid for each page render (if it's an SPA), if it's not an SPA it gets trickier.